# System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException when publishing on IIS, working fine in IIS express

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, ssl

I have a SOAP client that works well in IIS Express, but it throws the following exception when published on IIS:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:  Could not
>   establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority ....

This is the function that creates the client with its security options:

```
internal static MixedBulkServices.MixedBulkServicesClient GetMixedBulkService(string endPoint)
{
    //Defines a secure binding with certificate authentication
    WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

    //Creates ServiceClient, attach transport-binding, Endpoint and the loaded certificate
    MixedBulkServices.MixedBulkServicesClient service = new MixedBulkServices.MixedBulkServicesClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(endPoint));

    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(GetCertificatePath(), Properties.Settings.Default.PrivateKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

    service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;

    return service;
}
```

I Have installed all .NET 4.6 options and WCF Services in the server.
Any advice will be much appreciated

Comment: The AppPool user has access and authorization to the folder where the certificates are stored? That could be the problem

Comment: Yes, it has access rights. Thanks